# What is the difference between Azure Databricks and Azure Batch AI?

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service, databricks, azure-cognitive-services

I have went throught the documentation of both Microsoft AI services https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch-ai/overview and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/databricks/ but I still can't understand the difference or when each should be used(purpose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft AI is a first party solution Microsoft built, Databricks is based off of Apache Spark that we will manage for you in Azure.  One of the things we are trying to do in Azure is meet the customer where they are most comfortable.  In a way it's similar to how we have Service Fabric (Microsoft Service) and Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).  Both allow you to run microservices but one is a service we developed and the other is a managed Open Source Project we support.

When to use each is more of a question of preference and skillset.

Comment: I'd want a more detailed answer tho if possible another way to put it is advantages and disadvantages of each over the other if possible.

Comment: While both are managed services, you have more flexibility with MS AI as it's just one piece of our larger platform.  Databricks is more of a packaged solution that I think might be easier for newcomers or those already using Apache Spark.  Databricks also can be run on other platforms so if you are worried about vendor lock-in you might go that route.   In the end there is no IFTTT diagram that will tell you to use one over the other.